# caret train glm training error - empty result

Tags: r, machine-learning, glm, r-caret

I have a dataset with a number of binary predictors and binary outcome. I am trying to use logistic regression to predict the outcome and use caret package.

For some reason, after training my model does not produce result, but finishes without any errors. However, when I train with cross-validation, I get the result.

```
> Model = train(success ~ . - contestid - index - tags, data = p.train, 
+               method = "glm",
+               family = binomial(link = "logit"),
+               trControl = trainControl(method = "none"));
Warning message:
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 
> Model$results
[1] Accuracy  Kappa     parameter
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

With cross-validation:

```
> Model = train(success ~ . - contestid - index - tags, data = p.train, 
+                 method = "glm",
+                 family = binomial(link = "logit"),
+                 trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"));
There were 22 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> Model$results
  parameter Accuracy     Kappa AccuracySD  KappaSD
1      none      0.8 0.4208333  0.1972027 0.460482
> Model$resample
   Accuracy      Kappa Resample
1      0.75  0.5000000   Fold01
2      0.50  0.2000000   Fold02
3      1.00  1.0000000   Fold03
4      0.75  0.5000000   Fold04
5      1.00  1.0000000   Fold05
6      1.00         NA   Fold06
7      0.75  0.5000000   Fold07
8      0.75  0.0000000   Fold08
9      0.50 -0.3333333   Fold09
10     1.00         NA   Fold10
```

All warnings are the same, about the fitted probabilities, since my data allows perfect separation. However, this does not prevent training with cv to produce results.

What might be the reason for the absence of results in the first case?

Thanks

Comment: Using `"none"` produces single model. No parameters optimization is done. Thus the field `results` is empty. You can check `glm.fit$finalModel`

Comment: `DrDom` has the correct diagnosis